# Масштабирование изображения под фиксированные размеры ImageView

Tags: android, изображения

Есть ImageView, ширина которого match_parent и высота 200dp. 
Приложение выгружает изображение с сервера и устанавливает его в ImageView.
Как масштабировать/заполнить ImageView, чтобы изображение заполняло весь ImageView, сохраняя пропорции?

[image: Пример]

Стоит учитывать, что разрешения изображений варьируются, как и их ориентация (портретная/альбомная)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это должно подойти:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

Comment: Действительно подошло. Большое спасибо!